# Is it possible to stop a device connected as host charging connected device

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Is it possible to stop a device connected in host mode from charging the connected device?

Update:

I am running as root, and will take any hacks that work.

Comment: Not via the Android SDK. Perhaps there's some hack at the Linux level if you are running as root.